# Extract two optional columns into a case class in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I have the following types in the application:

```scala
case class Widget(
    id: Int,
    name: String,
    latlon: Option[Latlon],
)

case class Latlon(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
```

I'd like to store widgets in a table with columns `id`, `name`, `latitude` and `longitude` (the last two being optional). I don't care what happens when only one of the latlon columns is NULL and the other isn't.

(Some databases have special column types to store geographical coordinates. Please ignore that for the purposes of the question, as the types have been simplified.)

I've tried declaring the table like this:

```scala
  class Widgets(tag: Tag) extends Table[Widget](tag, Some(mySchema), "widgets") {
    def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name")
    def latitude: Rep[Option[Double]] = column[Option[Double]]("latitude")
    def longitude: Rep[Option[Double]] = column[Option[Double]]("longitude")

    def toLatlon(value: (Option[Double], Option[Double])): Option[Latlon] =
      Applicative[Option].map2(value._1, value._2)(Latlon.apply)

    def fromLatlon(value: Option[Latlon]): Option[(Option[Double], Option[Double])] =
      value.map(latlon => (Some(latlon.latitude), Some(latlon.longitude)))

    def * =
      (
        id.?,
        name,
        alternateNames,
        (latitude, longitude) <> (toLatlon, fromLatlon),
      ) <> (Widget.apply _ tupled, Widget.unapply)
  }
```

This works for fetching data, but when inserting data *without* a `latlon`, an error is raised:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:366)
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:364)
at slick.lifted.ShapedValue.$anonfun$$less$greater$1(Shape.scala:279)
at scala.Function1.$anonfun$andThen$1(Function1.scala:57)
at slick.relational.TypeMappingResultConverter.set(ResultConverter.scala:135)
at slick.relational.ProductResultConverter.set(ResultConverter.scala:68)
at slick.relational.ProductResultConverter.set(ResultConverter.scala:43)
at slick.relational.TypeMappingResultConverter.set(ResultConverter.scala:135)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$SingleInsertAction.$anonfun$run$15(JdbcActionComponent.scala:521)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef.withPreparedInsertStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:432)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef.withPreparedInsertStatement$(JdbcBackend.scala:429)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.withPreparedInsertStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:489)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$ReturningInsertActionComposerImpl.preparedInsert(JdbcActionComponent.scala:662)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$SingleInsertAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:519)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleJdbcProfileAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:30)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleJdbcProfileAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:27)
at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.liftedTree1$1(BasicBackend.scala:275)
at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.run(BasicBackend.scala:275)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

(The extra `Option` in `fromLatlon` is there because apparently the type of `<>` requires it.)

I've made another attempt using [Slick documentation for custom case class mapping](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.0/userdefined.html#monomorphic-case-classes):

```scala
case class LiftedLatlon(latitude: Rep[Double], longitude: Rep[Double])

implicit object LatlonShape extends CaseClassShape(LiftedLatlon.tupled, Latlon.apply _ tupled)

def * =
  (
    id.?,
    name,
    alternateNames,
    LiftedLatlon(latitude, longitude),
  ) <> (Widget.apply _ tupled, Widget.unapply)
```

It seems that this would have worked for a required column, but it the types of `latitude`, `longitude` and the first argument of `<>` do not match because in the `Widget` class, `latlon` is optional.

How to group the two optional fields I have into one, and be able to insert the whole value without the optional part?

Why is there asymmetry in the arguments of `<>` (`f: (U => R), g: (R => Option[U]`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the last argument of `<>` is *required* to return a `Some`. I don't have a confirmation from the documentation, but that would correspond to the typical use case of using the (apply, unapply) pair, as the `unapply` allows for failure. The implementation of `<>` explicitly unpacks the expected `Some` ([Shape.scala:279](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/ddb75a0f96fdde48bbb6885c4636bae204515a69/slick/src/main/scala/slick/lifted/Shape.scala#L279)) by using its argument `g` as `g.andThen(_.get)`.

Therefore, to fix the original problem `fromLatlon` has to be rewritten as:

```scala
def fromLatlon(value: Option[Latlon]): Option[(Option[Double], Option[Double])] = 
  Some(
    (value.map(_.latitude), value.map(_.longitude))
  )
```

Comment: ok, perfect! in this way you always manage to internally evaluate the individual values...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more convenient for you to write a single column in the database, maybe it could be **String**, and use a separator, example ";" .... I'll use an example of how it should work doing a Mapped from String to Option [LatLon]

Disclaimer: I did not try it but we have many similar examples working with Mappeds...

**Mapped**

```
trait LatLonMapped {
  self: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] =>

  import dbConfig.profile.api._

  implicit val latLonColumnType: BaseColumnType[Option[LatLon]] = MappedColumnType.base[Option[LatLon], String](
    optLatLon => optLatLon.map(_.toColumnDb).getOrElse(""),
    str => LatLon(str) someOnlyIf str.isEmpty
  )


  /**
    * Util for Options Some..... package utils in my project common
    *
    * @example {{{body someOnlyIf body.length > 0}}}
    */
  implicit class CondOptExtensions[T](x: => T) {
    def someOnlyIf(cond: Boolean): Option[T] = if (cond) Some(x) else None
  }

}
```

**Your classes and some adjustments**

```
case class Widget(id: Int, name: String, latLon: Option[LatLon])

case class LatLon(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
  def toColumnDb: String = latitude.toString + LatLon.delimiter + longitude.toString
}

object LatLon extends (String => LatLon) {
  val delimiter = ";"

  override def apply(str: String): LatLon = {
    val values = str.split(delimiter).map(_.toDouble)
    val latitude: Double = values.head
    val longitude: Double = values(1)
    LatLon(latitude, longitude)
  }

}

trait WidgetMapping extends LatLonMapped {
  self: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] =>

  import dbConfig.profile.api._

  class Widgets(tag: Tag) extends Table[Widget](tag, "widgets") {
    def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name")

    def latLon: Rep[Option[LatLon]] = column[Option[LatLon]]("latLon")


    def * = (
      id,
      name,
      latLon,
    ) <> (Widget.tupled, Widget.unapply)
  }

 val AllWidgets = TableQuery[Widgets]

}
```

**Remember**: the column in the database, if you do not have something that generates it automatically, you must generate it as String, for this to work, for example, my evolution generator created these queries for MySQL:

```
# --- !Ups

create table `widgets` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`name` TEXT NOT NULL,`latLon` TEXT NOT NULL);


# --- !Downs

drop table `widgets`;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I'm looking for. With a single column, I cannot efficiently query the value of, for example, `latitude` in the database.